# Howto add PostCSS plugin to the Gatsby SASS plugin

Tags: sass, gatsby, postcss

I have a Gatsby site with sass support using the `gatsby-plugin-sass` plugin. That works, but now I want to add PostCSS support.

According to the [warning on this page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-postcss-sass) (a deprecated plugin) this now should be possible by defining the postcss plugin in the `postCssPlugins` options.

Indeed, the [sass plugin documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-sass/) tells me I can add a postcss plugin to the options, but it's unclear to me how to do this exactly. I already added the `gatsby-plugin-postcss` plugin separately and am now trying to integrate it with the sass plugin.

This does not work:

**gatsby-config.js:**

```
    // SASS support with PostCSS support:
    `gatsby-plugin-postcss`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
      options: {
        postCssPlugins: ['gatsby-plugin-postcss'],
      },
    },
```

I guess I should call it in a different way but I can't find any documentation on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gatsby-plugin-postcss` use specific postcss plugin(`postcss-preset-env`, for example) to handle css code, itself is not a postcss plugin, so you can't use it in `postCssPlugins` option.

And the pipeline for gastby to handle sass file is `sass -> postcss plugin -> final result`, so just use sass plugin and choose postcss in its option `postCssPlugins`.

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
  options: {
    postCssPlugins: [
      require(`postcss-preset-env`)({
        stage: 2,
        features: {
          "nesting-rules": true,
        },
      }),
    ],
    precision: 6,
  },
},
```

Comment: Thanks, pretty obvious actually :)